# VBA Code. Trying to fix the "IF" PARTS

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this written in my VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G9:G28")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If IsNumeric(.Value) Then .Value = .Value / 100
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

When I try to erase the data in the "G" Cells a 0% stays locked in. I think bc ".Value/100" is the 0% that my code says must go inside that cell. The above code is suppose to turn any number into a percentage but I think I wrote it and when its suppose to be blank it shows a "0%" but I want it to be blank.

Comment: this is probably because of formatting. I don't know how to fix it, that's jsut a hint.

Comment: Try just tweaking to `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G9:G28")) Is Nothing And Not IsEmpty(Target) Then`

Comment: use `If IsNumeric(.Text) Then .Value = .Value / 100`

Comment: @FriedEgg, did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G9:G28")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count <= 1 Then ' make sure not more than 1 cell is changed
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Target
            If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
                If .Value = 0 Then
                    .Value = ""
                Else
                    .Value = .Value / 100
                End If
            End If
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Holy moly! This worked. I'll go over it and understand it better. Thank you. I will check mark it when my 6 minutes are up

Comment: Cells that should be deleted will now contain the empty string instead of nothing (beeing empty) - that's probably not what was intended. Furthermore, entering a value of 0 removes the number and converts the cell's content to an empty string as well. Certainly not what was intended!

Comment: @Leviathan - `Range("A1").Value = "": Debug.Print IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) '<-- True`

Comment: @Comintern that's not true in all circumstances (e.g. if the cell is formatted as text). You should clear the cell if you want it to be empty. In this case, however, it probably won't matter at all as the cells in question are formatted as percent. But still, setting an empty cell to empty isn't useful at all.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a loop:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G9:G28")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each r In Intersect(Target, Range("G9:G28"))
                If IsNumeric(r.Value) Then r.Value = r.Value / 100
            Next r
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

*This code will allow more than one cell to be changed.*

Answer (score 0):

Target can be SEVERAL cells.
And an array divided by 100 makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just test if the cell in question is empty with `IsEmpty(Target.Value)` before performing the conversion to percent, like this:

```
If Not IsEmpty(.Value) And IsNumeric(.Value) Then .Value = .Value / 100
```